# Reshape and conccatente arrays in 4D to 3D

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

l'm working with 4D arrays in numpy. l would like to append the data in forth dimension as follow :

1)
inputs :

```
data_1_1=dim(2,4,130,10)
data_1_2=dim(2,4,130,10)
```

expected output :

```
data_1=dim(2,4,130,20)
```

2) reduce 4D array to 3D array
inputs :

```
data_2_1=dim(3,5,130,20)
```

expected output :

```
data_2_1=dim(15,130,20)
```

Sorry for my newbie question.

Thank you for your help

**What l have tried ?**
1)

```
data_1= np.concatenate((data_1_1[...,np.newaxis],data_1_2[...,np.newaxis]),axis=2)
```

l'm wondering if this solution do the right job. since l would like to concatenate on the last dimension. In which order it's done ?
Is is correct ?

2) For this case l don't have any idea

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: @ForceBru, please see my update to see what l have tried . Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part you need to say you want a specific axis to work on:

```
>>>x=np.arange(2*4*130*10).reshape(2,4,130,10)
>>>np.concatenate((x,x),axis=3).shape
(2, 4, 130, 20)
```

and for the second part, sounds like you want a [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```
>>>y=np.arange(3*5*130*20).reshape(3,5,130,20)
>>> y.reshape(15,130,20).shape
(15, 130, 20)
```

The `numpy` terms you need to acquaint yourself with are axis and shape - a good read on these will help you a lot.